# Find duplicates with a suffix in excel and keep results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I have a spreadsheet with a list of items in one column (A) and in column C shows the total sold. I'm trying to find all the items within column A.

The issue is, some items are the same, only they have a suffix, mostly separated by a -. The values in column C would be different as well.

Example:
ABC                          = 5

ABC-123 = 3

ABC-543 = 2

I'm looking to identify only 123 and then combine all the values, so that it will show ABC and 10 as the total.

I've looked around how to remove the duplicate suffix, but have so far failed to find a method when trying to add the total values.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean the data you have looks like this:

```
column A column B column C
ABC                 5
ABC-123             3
ABC-543             2
```

if so, you can select `column A` then go to `data` then `text to columns` then `delimited` select `other` by putting `-` sign, `next` and `finish`.

result must be:

```
column A column B column C
ABC                      5
ABC      123             3
ABC      543             2
```

then you can `=sumifs(C:C;A:A;"ABC")` (keep in mind that column B must be empty)

if you have `ABC-123 = 3` in the same cell as a text, then you can do:

```
=IF(SEARCH("ABC";F3);RIGHT(F3;LEN(F3)-FIND("=";F3)-1);"")
```

where `F3` is equal to `ABC-123 = 3` The formula above searches fo `ABC` and gives you a value after `=` sign, no matter how long this value is. If there is no `ABC` it will return an error.

if there is no need to look for `ABC` then just use:

```
=RIGHT(F3;LEN(F3)-FIND("=";F3)-1)
```

I hope this helps. I cannot comment, so ask if you have questions. 
Best - AB

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, the data looks like column A - ABC-123,  Column B has the values.

Comment: Column B has the values of sold. Column C has where the item sold.   I had been using =SUMIF($A:$A,"*"&A2&"*",$B:$B) to get total sold, but I used your text to columns method to remove the suffix, so probably not necessary to use this formula.   I also created two new columns to find out total of where the item was sold using =COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"Shop*") but it's not so accurate as it doesn't include if there were multiple values in Column B. I then copy the values to a new sheet and delete the duplicates.  Is there a quicker/easier way to do this?  Many thanks